# Responsive overlay over a background image (of a list item)

Tags: css, list, responsive-design, background-image, overlay

I'm trying to figure out how to create an overlay that mirrors the height and width of the background image on browser resize.

I've found some nifty answers on SO for inline images and situations where a responsive height is unimportant but nothing that responds to both height and width changes of background images.

As always, an example from [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLC_x02210/1nucgjdj/4/) may be helpful.

HTML:

```
<ul class="two_boxes">
    <li class="sun">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="sun">
        <div class="overlay"></div> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.two_boxes{
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 940px;
    height: 448px;
    padding-top: 0px;   
    position: relative;
}

.sun{
    background-image: url('sun_banner.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    width: 48%;
    max-width: 458px; 
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 448px;
    display: inline-block; 
}

.overlay{   
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100; 
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.sun:hover .overlay{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: You can change width and height using media queries.

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't know the natural height of the background-image?

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/1nucgjdj/6/

```
<ul class="two_boxes">
    <li class="sun">

        <img src = "http://www.sideswipedesigns.com/test/sun_banner.jpg" width="100%" />
         <div class="overlay"></div>
    </li>

     <li class="sun">

               <img src = "http://www.sideswipedesigns.com/test/sun_banner.jpg" width="100%" />
         <div class="overlay"></div>
    </li> 
 </ul>



.two_boxes {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 940px;
    height: 448px;
    padding-top: 0px;   
    position: relative;
}

.sun {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 48%;
    min-height:auto;
    max-width: 458px; 
    max-height: 448px;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

.overlay  {     
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 100; 
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    position:absolute;
    top:auto;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.sun:hover .overlay {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, that works great. The only issue is I'd like it to work on background-images for the sake of completeness.